# How do you get rid of these small transparent pixel lines in a svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having some problems when I imported my svg image as a background in css, it seems like one of the mountains in my background have this small transparent lines. But for some reason it only appears in Chrome but not FireFox.
Thanks.
[image]

[image: closeup]

here's the [fiddleJS](https://jsfiddle.net/7fe9rvjx/)

```
.
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1440" height="328.656" viewBox="0 0 1440 328.656" style="shape-rendering: geometricPrecision">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        filter: url(#filter);
      }

      .cls-2 {
        filter: url(#filter-2);
      }

      .cls-3 {
        fill: #47c9af;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
    <filter id="filter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset result="offset" dx="81.915" dy="57.358" in="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur result="blur"/>
      <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#34495e"/>
      <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feBlend result="blend" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="filter-2" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset result="offset" dx="42.596" dy="29.826" in="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur result="blur"/>
      <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#16a085"/>
      <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feBlend result="blend" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="mountain.svg" class="cls-1">
    <g id="_" data-name="&gt;" class="cls-2">
      <path id="Polygon_1" data-name="Polygon 1" class="cls-3" d="M-1.8,845.344L135.187,1083h-273.97Z" transform="translate(0 -812.344)"/>
      <path id="Polygon_1_copy" data-name="Polygon 1 copy" class="cls-3" d="M272.186,903.344L409.171,1141H135.2Z" transform="translate(0 -812.344)"/>
      <path id="Polygon_1_copy_2" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 2" class="cls-3" d="M546.171,845.344L683.156,1083H409.186Z" transform="translate(0 -812.344)"/>
      <path id="Polygon_1_copy_3" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 3" class="cls-3" d="M820.155,903.344L957.14,1141H683.17Z" transform="translate(0 -812.344)"/>
      <path id="Polygon_1_copy_4" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 4" class="cls-3" d="M1094.14,845.344L1231.12,1083H957.155Z" transform="translate(0 -812.344)"/>
      <path id="Polygon_1_copy_5" data-name="Polygon 1 copy 5" class="cls-3" d="M1308.12,812.344L1445.11,1050H1171.14Z" transform="translate(0 -812.344)"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Er, you'll have to give us the SVG - a png of it's not going to be of any use. Edit it into your post.

Comment: Thanks, i have supplied it bellow [link](https://jsfiddle.net/7fe9rvjx/)

Comment: I'm still looking, but notice that if I scroll the thing horizontally in the fiddle or the snippet in your post, the lines have a fixed position in the window and thus affect a different part of the image, rather than moving as one may have expected at first. I wonder it has something to do with either (0) the  polygons overlapping or (1) there being an ever so slight gap between them - (due to floating point error, I guess)

Comment: I have noticed it too.

Comment: It has to do something with chome or web-kit

Comment: Okay, well in that case you could chase it down, submit a bug report and wait. Or... you could just be a little more verbose and do away with the cloning trick, simply drawing each polygon that you need to see, chucking out the filters too. Sure, the file will grow by a bit, but it's still going to be light-weight, so good enough will be far better than a broken attempt at perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a drawing bug in webkit/Chrome that seems to be triggered by the repeated use of feOffset to layer content more than 3 layers deep.  If you resize the iframe in the jsfiddle, you'll see that the thin lines stay fixed relative to the parent window, not the content - so it seems to be a low level bug. Based on my experiments, any shape that is 4 or more layers deep gets the drawing artifact.

Easiest way to fix is to define your shape once in defs and utilize multiple `use` elements to place and color them.

I've filed [bug#660745](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660745) with Chrome.

(That said - your filters have badly specified primitives (no stdDeviation for the (unused) GaussianBlur, no filter dimensions, no mode for the feBlend) that you should fix. These are better specified versions of your filters.)

```
<filter id="filter" >
  <feOffset result="offset" dx="81.915" dy="57.358" in="SourceAlpha"/>
  <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#34495e"/>
  <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="offset"/>
  <feBlend mode="normal" result="blend" in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter-2">
  <feOffset result="offset" dx="42.596" dy="29.826" in="SourceAlpha"/>
  <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#16a085"/>
  <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="offset"/>
  <feBlend mode="normal" result="blend" in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
```